# How to use Binding with FormatString

Tags: xamarin, binding, label, string-formatting

I'm trying to display a Lable.Text using a Binding with a string (Tables: ) followed by an Integer(TableCount).

I've tried using:

`<Label x:Name="tableCountLable" Text="{Binding TableCount, StringFormat='Table Count: {0:N}'}" 
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>`.

Also, I've tried:

`<Label x:Name="tableCountLable">
       <Label.Text DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TableCount, StringFormat=Tables: {0:N}}" 
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</Label>`

In both cases, the preceding text (Tables: ) does not disply.  Only the integer (TableCount) displays.

[The integer cant be seen on the upper left of the button labeled "Tables"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCA0r.png)

I would appreciate someone pointing me to an answer.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

[StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting) docs

```
<Label Text="{Binding TableCount, StringFormat='Tables: {0}'}" />
```

Comment: it really should be that simple.  Are you sure your Label isn't truncated?  Are you using the latest version for Forms?

Answer (score 0):

I write a demo about it, Here is running GIF.

[image]

I used your `StringFormat` code like following format.

```
   <Label Text="{Binding Count ,  StringFormat=' Table Count: {0:N}' } "
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                                               FontSize="Large"
                                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

My version of xamarin forms nuget package is 4.5.0.530 .

I update my demo to github, you can download it.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/MyCusListview.zip

Comment: Are there any update for this issue, If the answer it helpful, Please don’t forget to mark this answer(click the ☑️ at the top left corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issues.